# Frobenius Method to solve $x^2y''+3xy'+(4x+4)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, Im trying to self-learn method of frobenius, and I would like to ask if someone can explain to me how can we solve the following DE using this method.
$x^2y''+3xy'+(4x+4)y=0$

Comment: I know that it have only one answer in terms of series of Frobenius and I would like to find that answer.